# Angular Universal Prerendering Issue with "/courses" Route

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, angularfire, angular-universal

I am experiencing an issue with prerendering the "/courses" route in my Angular Universal project. When running `ng run lungabros:serve-ssr`, the route works perfectly fine. However, when attempting to prerender the "/courses" route, the process gets stuck without any error messages.

**Steps Taken:**

- Checked the route configuration and implementation for any errors or issues.
- Verified that all dependencies are correctly installed and up to date.
- Tried to prerender only the "/courses" route to isolate the problem. I can confirm that it's that route causing issues.

**Issue Details:**

- Adding "/courses" to the `routes` array in `angular.json` causes the prerendering process to get stuck at message "*⠙ Prerendering {n} route(s) to /Users/.../lungabros/dist/lungabros/browser...*".
- No error messages or logs are provided during the prerendering process.
- I have not found any verbose logging flag to inspect deeper the issue.
- Other routes work fine during prerendering.
- I have tried running the prerendering process with different options
  and flags, but the issue persists.

**Repository:**
I have a public repository available in [GitHub](https://github.com/plungarini/lungabros) that contains the code for my Angular Universal project.

#### Update

Looking for suggestions online for PWAs and SSR apps issues, i came across few suggestions saying that one of the possible errors in this case is when you have a valuechanges connections with firebase. This could throw issues because your app (which is now a server) listen for an observable that never completes. As my `/courses` route has an real time listener (observable) with my firebase database I tought that piping with `take(1)` would help. Unfortunately not.

Comment: Does the page send ajax calls during SSR? Is this on your live webserver?

Comment: My SSR app only make requests to Firebase Firestore and Firebase Functions. I tried to limit a never ending observable by using take(1) as I said, but still doesn’t work. The app is now live on lungabros.it You can also look at my GitHub repo if that helps!